# How to save Koala search results to Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

I have seen several short answers on how to initialize a connection to Facebook using koala and to then do a search using @graph.graph_call type method call, but I have not seen anyone explain how to then get the results from that search and save them into a Rails database.  Do I have to create my own resource to match the json format that koala returns from Facebook and then save objects of those types into the rails database?  Or, does koala have methods to handle that for me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to persist the fetched data on your own. You might need to create your own resource or add columns to existing tables. It depends on what you want to do.

For example, Code for finding or creating a user by facebook user id will be look like this:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_fb_access_token)
user_info = graph.get_object(:me, fields: %w(email))

user = User.find_or_create_by(fb_user_id: fb_user_id) do |new_user|
  new_user.email = user_info['email']
  new_user.password = SecureRandom.hex
end
```

in this case, you need to add `fb_user_id` column to users table.

Comment: ok thanks.  i was hoping their might be some kind of "import" feature in ruby on rails that would allow me to tell it to use a model definition in koala that matches facebook's json types for places and events etc and use it with the generate scaffold company to do it for me.  Thanks.